# What does this output mean?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I've been checking some `Mathematica notebooks` availbe [here](https://www.notebookarchive.org/collection-pod?collection=wolfram-summer-school-2021).
One of the plot avaible in them is.

```
   ResourceFunction["ExtrinsicCurvedManifoldToGraph"][x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}, {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 0.8, 510]["PureSpatialGraph"]
```

which results in a nice graph.

I wanted to increase the number of point, this works for some numbers (for example 520).
But if I put the resulting number to be 1000, that is I have the code

```
   ResourceFunction["ExtrinsicCurvedManifoldToGraph"][x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}, {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 0.8,1000]["PureSpatialGraph"]
```

the output that I get is [image: putput of function above].

How can I get this to plot? I've tried exporting this but I just got the same thing in jpg format.

PS: Sorry for the screenshot but I found no better way to show this.

Comment: Large graphs are not visualized automatically. Use `GraphPlot` to force visualization. This has been asked many times before, but I don't have time to find a duplicate candidate.

Comment: Thank you. I will close the question.

Comment: Yes, thank you.